Reference for semirings with exponentiation
A commutative semiring $R$ with exponentiation has an additional operation $R \times R \to R, (a, b) \mapsto a^b$ (called exponentiation), satisfying the following six axioms ($\forall a, b, c \in R$):

$a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$
$a^0=1$
$(ab)^c=a^cb^c$
$1^c=1$ (redundant)
$a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$
$a^1=a$

For example, the nonnegative integers form a semiring with exponentiation being the usual one (note that $0^0=1$).
But is there any reference mentioning commutative semirings with exponentiation and the above six axioms? Note that the fourth axiom is actually redundant, as it follows from the second and fifth axioms.

It's a very natural notion I find (the set of isomorphism classes of a [small] cartesian closed category with coproducts carries such a structure, and there are many of these). I thought "exponential rig" might be an extant term, but on a quick search I only found https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.04790, which offers only very partial support. Possibly "Tarski high school algebra", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_high_school_algebra_problem, could provide more search terms.

some people in model theory - kirby, marker, wilkie, zilber, and others - study fields with exponentiation, so you may find something that interests you
